# python tkinter canvas when rectangle clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to make a function run when I click a rectangle on a tk canvas.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

c = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)

def clear():
    canvas.delete(ALL)

playbutton = c.create_rectangle(75, 25, 225, 75, fill="red")
playtext = c.create_text(150, 50, text="Play", font=("Papyrus", 26), fill='blue')

c.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: have you tried using the canvas `bind` method?

Comment: Have a look at the `.tag_bind` method [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html)

Answer (score 19):

You can add tags on the items you want to bind events to.
The event you want here is `<Button-1>`, which is left mousebutton.
To apply this to your example, you can do like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas

window = Tk()

c = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)

def clear():
    canvas.delete(ALL)

def clicked(*args):
    print("You clicked play!")

playbutton = c.create_rectangle(75, 25, 225, 75, fill="red",tags="playbutton")
playtext = c.create_text(150, 50, text="Play", font=("Papyrus", 26), fill='blue',tags="playbutton")

c.tag_bind("playbutton","<Button-1>",clicked)

c.pack()

window.mainloop()
```